# Unity container usage in UWP

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, prism

I am trying to develop Prism 6 UWP Application .
My current problem is I want to register all objects used in Application with Unity Dependency injection container .
But so many UI objects are created by infrastructure(Activator.CreateInstance(type)) and no way to trigger their creation through dependency injection conatiner.I would be fine even if I register created objects with DI conatiner.
I refered Github sample application AdventureWorks.Shopper in Prism samples.
Here I saw views are created by infrastructure ,but some other objects are created by Dependency injection conatiner .

Is there any way to get all objects in applications and register them with DI conatiner ?

Is there any way to get all objects in applications and register them with DI container or trigger all creation through DI conatiner?

Comment: Are you looking to register a set of object through the dependency container that you can reflect into? Could you reflect over the types in the loaded assemblies and load them into the DI container with their instantiation method being Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: If I do so , I get duplicate objects .Some UI objects are displayed by framework.So actual UI gets displayed with this object.But my DI container has another instance of the same class

Comment: One way , we found ,we can access container like this unityContainer = (UnityContainer)((Prism.Unity.Windows.PrismUnityApplication)Application.Current).Container;.
   Object which are created by framework  can be registered with unity by adding registrations in constructor api   example
            unityContainer.RegisterInstance<PatientInfoGroup>(this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't try to have your UI objects created by the container, because as you mention, the XAML parsing process (infrastructure as you call it) is responsible for doing that and there is no easy way to get in the loop to take over that construction process.

This is one of the reasons we added the ViewModelLocator to Prism - so that from the ViewModel down through all of its dependencies, you can wire up the SetDefaultViewModelFactory method to use the container to do the construction of all your ViewModels and their dependencies (and their dependency's dependencies, etc.) as long as you use ViewModelLocator to wire the View to the ViewModel.

If you are following the MVVM pattern well, then there should almost never be a need to construct the UI objects themselves through the container because they should not be doing any logic in the code behind that would depend on things injected by the container. But that is not to say you will *never* need to do that. So for those situations where you need to do that You can either get to the container through the Application.Current as suggested by S Vasudev with some casting. Or if you need to do that a few places and don't want all that casting "noise" in the code, then write a simple helper object with a static property that you can set in the OnInitializeAsync method of the App class and then easily access anywhere.

If you are doing that in more than a few places you should start to question your design. And yes statics (globals) are evil and should be avoided whenever possible. But if it is just a few places in the code behind of a few views, sometimes you need to be a pragmatic programmer who gets things done and not an MVVM purist who overcomplicates things just to avoid a few minor violations of the MVVM guidance.

Answer (score 0):

One way we found :-
You can access unity container like this :-
unityContainer = (UnityContainer)((Prism.Unity.Windows.PrismUnityApplication)Application.Current).Container;

In constructor of  objects which are created by Activator.CreateInstance,we can use unity container and register that instance to unity container.

In that way , all objects gets registered with unity conatiner
example:-
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(this);